# Mustache(icanhaz) iterating array of arrays

Tags: javascript, mustache

In mustache if we have an array like :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
```

We can create template like:

```
{{#a}}
{{.}}
{{/a}}
```

to iterate over it. Now if we have some thing like

```
var a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Can we create a template like:

```
{{#a}}
key is {{0th element}} and the value is {{1st element}}
{{/a}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tried out things and got the solution:
We can do the following:

```
var htm = '{{#names}}'+
            '<p> value="{{0}}" key = "{{1}}"</p>'+
          '{{/names}}';
ich.addTemplate('formNameOptionsHTML',htm);
var arr =[[0,1],[10,11],[20,21]];
var htm = ich.formNameOptionsHTML({names:arr});
$('body').append(htm);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Tkc2/) is the jsfiddle link to it.