# Iterate over an array using mustache

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, mustache

I have an array which is like that :

```js
[
  [
    ['name of the product', unique id],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb]
  ], 
  [
    ['name of the product', unique id],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb]
  ], 
  [
    ['name of the product', unique id],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb]
  ], 
  [
    ['name of the product', unique id],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb],
    [nb, nb]
  ]
]
```

and I would like to iterate over it using mustache. My aim is to create a table with the name of the product and a number of stars for three criterias.

I tried to access with normal language {{thename[0]} does not work.

I know it would be easier with an object of array or an array of objects but changing my datas is going to be hard.

Edit : I tried this. It almost works but shows me the first characters of 'name of the product' and 'unique id' while i wanted only 'name of the product' (and the whole world).

```js
{{#product}}
    {{#0}}
        {{#0}}
            <p>{{.}}</p>
        {{/0}}
    {{/0}}
{{/product}}
```

Comment: I just read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582722/mustacheicanhaz-iterating-array-of-arrays but it works only on one level

Comment: Thanx but it does not seems to work.

Comment: does `{{#.}} / {{.}}`  work? if not, you'll have to transform/massage the input data before you send it to be rendered. it usually easier to bend the data than to bend the template. edit: it looks like you just need `{{#product.0}}`

Comment: That is what i am going to do. Thanks for the help.